# Using 当然 as an exclamation?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

I'm wondering...

To answer someone's question as to whether something is so or not, can you simply reply, "of course it is!" just as we do in English?

Example: 
Can you swim？ (你会游泳吗？）
Of course I can swim! (As in, that's a ridiculous question). (当然啊！）

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “江主席你觉得董先生连任好不好啊？” “好啊。” “中央也支持他吗？” “当然啦。”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In fact, you can use any word as an exclamation, especially in speech. I'm not aware of any language where this is ungrammatical. Example:

> Q: What's your favourite Chinese word?
>
> A: 当然！

Comment: @sulfly yes. It is correct grammatically, and used in daily conversation.